# Prove the limit case: if $\alpha,\beta$ are countable ordinals, then $\alpha+\beta$ is also countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, ordinals, transfinite-induction

I am trying to prove that if $\alpha,\beta$ are countable ordinals, then $\alpha+\beta$ is also countable.

Both base and successor case has been done, now I am considering the limit case. Once I assume that $\forall \beta< \gamma, \alpha+\beta$ is countable, what should I do to conclude that $\sup\lbrace \alpha+\beta\mid\beta<\gamma\rbrace$ is also countable?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The version of definition of ordinal I use here: An ordinal is a set $\alpha$ such that:
[image]

Comment: Assuming $\gamma$ is countable, it's a sup of countably many countable ordinals.  So technically, what you should be proving by induction on $\beta$ is: $\beta ~ \mathrm{countable} \Rightarrow \alpha + \beta ~ \mathrm{countable}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I do know about it and I think it is the reason why we should induct on $\beta$. But still I cannot see how I can prove the limiting case. If possible, may I please ask for a proof?

Comment: It's just a general fact that the sup of a countable set of countable ordinals is countable.  If you haven't had that fact given to you, then I would need to know precisely what definition of ordinals you're using (e.g. notional equivalence classes of well-ordered sets in naive set theory? von Neumann ordinals in ZFC?) before I could outline a proof of that fact.  But in most cases, it should just reduce to the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: This is analogous to the union of disjoint countable sets being countable.

Comment: Just prove that the cardinality is the sum of the cardinalities.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I have edited to add the definition. Could you please have a look?

Comment: OK, that looks like von Neumann ordinals in ZFC - in that case, the sup of a family of ordinals is literally equal to its union, so the fact I referenced is a direct corollary of the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by taking the synthetic definition of addition. Let $A$ be a set well-ordered by an ordering of length $\alpha$, and $B$ likewise $\beta$. Then the ordinal sum $\alpha + \beta$ is given by ordering the set $A \sqcup B$ (where $\sqcup$ denotes the disjoint union) in a certain way so as to place a copy of $B$ after a copy of $A$. That set is countable, being the union of two countable sets.